# Una cadena contiene a otra

Tags: java

Buenas este es mi codigo, lo que pasa es que necesito saber si la cadena 1 contiene a la cadena 2, la cual esta separada por "," es obligatorio usar Tokenaizer para separar la cadena, pero al momento de usar el contains no me funciona, alguna sugerencia? gracias

```
    String palabra1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la palabra");   // No quiero perder interactiva
    String palabra2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la palabra");   // No q,perdi,er int,intep,quiero,int
```

//      String[] cadena= palabra1.split(" ");
//      String[] cadena2= palabra2.split(",");

```
    StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(palabra2,",");
        while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
            if(palabra1.contains(st.nextToken())) { //o palabra2 uso las 2 y no funciona
                System.out.println(st.nextElement() +": Si");
            }else System.out.println(st.nextElement() +": No");
 }
```

}
}

Comment: podrias ser mas claro y conciso.

Comment: ya intentaste con `palabra1.contains(palabra2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos problemas, uno es que el método nextToken solo lo debería usar una vez, y el otro problema es que no estás usando palabra2.

El código debería quedar así

```
while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
  String token = st.nextToken();
  if (token.equals(palabra2) {
    System.out.println("Sí");
  } else {
    System.out.println("No);
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te mencionaron, tienes un problema con el método nextToken()

```
    StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(palabra2,",");
        while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
            String element = st.nextToken();
            if(palabra1.contains(element) { //o palabra2 uso las 2 y no funciona
                System.out.println(element +": Si");
            }else System.out.println(element +": No");
 }
```